# RTK createEntityAdapter not getting relational data in list after save user in database

Tags: laravel, redux, redux-toolkit, createentityadapter

i have a list of users which getting data from database by using RTK createEntityAdapter.

API function code for getting list of users

```
public function index(){
    
    $roles = Role::all();
    $all_roles = [];
    
    foreach ($roles as $key => $role) {
        $obj_role = new \stdClass();
        $obj_role->id = $role->id;
        $obj_role->name = $role->title;
        array_push($all_roles,$obj_role);
    }
    return  response()->json([

        'users' => User::with('roles')->paginate(10),
        'roles' => $all_roles
   
    ]);

}
```

In the above code getting users and roles in response & showing list in react app by using RTK createEntityAdapter

userSlice.js

```
    import { createSlice,createEntityAdapter} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { HTTP_STATUS } from "../../src/constants";
import { fetchUsers, deleteUsers, saveUser } from "services/userService";

const userAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
  selectId: (user) => user.id,
})

const userSlice = createSlice({
name:'user',
initialState: userAdapter.getInitialState( 
  { loading: false,
    page: 1,
    total_pages: null,
    status: null,
    message: null,
    roles: []
   } ),
reducers:{
  pageByNumber: (state,{payload}) => {
    state.page = payload.page
  },
  nextPage: (state, {payload}) => {
    state.page = state.page++
  },
  previousPage: (state, {payload}) => {
    state.page = state.page--
  },
  clear: (state) => {
    state.status = null,
    state.message = null
  }
},
extraReducers: {

    [fetchUsers.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true,
      state.status = HTTP_STATUS.PENDING
    },
    [fetchUsers.fulfilled]: (state, {payload}) => {
      state.loading = false,
      state.page = payload.users.current_page,
      state.total_pages = Math.ceil(payload.users.total/payload.users.per_page),
      userAdapter.setAll(state, payload.users.data), 
      state.status = HTTP_STATUS.FULFILLED,
      state.roles = payload.roles   
    },
    [fetchUsers.rejected]: (state, {error}) => {
      state.loading = false,
      state.status = HTTP_STATUS.REJECTED,
      state.message = error.message
    },

    [deleteUsers.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true,
      state.status = HTTP_STATUS.PENDING
    },
    
    [deleteUsers.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false,
      userAdapter.removeOne(state, payload.id)    
    },
    [deleteUsers.rejected]: (state) => {
      state.loading = false
    },
    [saveUser.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true,
      state.status = HTTP_STATUS.PENDING
    },
    
    [saveUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
      state.loading = false,
      state.status = HTTP_STATUS.FULFILLED
      if(!payload.errors){
        userAdapter.addOne(state, payload.id),
        state.message = payload.message
      }
    },
    [saveUser.rejected]: (state,{error}) => {
      state.loading = false,
      state.status = HTTP_STATUS.REJECTED,
      state.message = error.message
    }

  },
});

export const userSelectors = userAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => state.user,
  )

export const {pageByNumber, nextPage, previousPage,clear} = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer
```

user/index.js

```
const roles = useSelector(state => state.user.roles);
const allUsers = useSelector(userSelectors.selectAll);
        useEffect(() => {
              dispatch(
                fetchUsers(currentPage))
                .then(unwrapResult)
                .then((obj) => console.log(obj))
                .catch((obj) => console.log({objErr: obj}))
            }, [dispatch])
    
    //listing HTML
    
    {
                        allUsers.map((ls,index) => (
                        <tr key={ls.id}> 
                            <td>{ls.id}</td>
                            <td>{ls.name}</td>
                            <td>{ls.email}</td>
                            <td>
                              {ls.status =="ACTIVE" ? <Badge color="success" pill>Active</Badge>:<Badge color="danger" pill>Inactive</Badge>}</td>
                            <td>
                              
                              {ls.roles.map((role) => (
                                role.title+" "
                              ))}
                              </td>
                            <td><Moment fromNow ago>{ls.created_at}</Moment> </td>
                            <td>
                              <Button variant="warning" size="sm" onClick={handleShow} >Edit</Button>{' '}
                              <Button  
                                onClick={e =>
                                    window.confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this user?") &&
                                    deleteUser(ls.id)
                                }
                                variant="danger"
                              size="sm">Delete</Button>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        ))
                        }
```

create.js

```
    import {Modal, Button, Form,Dropdown} from "react-bootstrap";
import  propTypes  from "prop-types";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Multiselect from 'multiselect-react-dropdown';
import { saveUser } from 'services/userService';
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import Notify from "components/Common/Notify";

function Create({handleClose,show,roles}) {
  const [selectedRoles, setSelectedRoles] = useState([]);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState([]);
  
  function onSelectRoles(selectedList, selectedItem) {
    selectedRoles.push(selectedItem.id)
  }

  function onRemoveRole(selectedList, removedItem) {
    var index = selectedRoles.indexOf(removedItem.id)
    selectedRoles.splice(index, 1);
  }
  
  const message = useSelector(state => state.user.message);
  const status = useSelector(state => state.user.status);
  function onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let data ={
      name:name,
      email:email,
      password:password,
      roles:selectedRoles,
    }
    dispatch(
      saveUser(data))
      .then(unwrapResult)
      .then((obj) => {
        if(obj.errors){
          setErrors(obj.errors);
        }else{
          setErrors([]);
          handleClose();
        }
      }
        )
      .catch((obj) => {

        console.log({objErr: obj})
      })
  }

    return (
       <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
<Modal.Header closeButton>
  <Modal.Title>New User</Modal.Title>
</Modal.Header>
<Modal.Body>
{status && message && (
<Notify status={status} message={message}/>
)}
<Form onSubmit={onSubmit} >
<Form.Group className="mb-3">
    <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control className={errors['name'] ? "is-invalid" : ""} type="text" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value) } placeholder="Enter Name" />
    {errors['name'] ? 
    <Form.Text className="text-danger">
      {errors['name']}
    </Form.Text>
    :''
    }
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control className={errors['email'] ? "is-invalid" : ""} type="email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value) } placeholder="Enter email" />
    {errors['email'] ? 
    <Form.Text className="text-danger">
      {errors['email']}
    </Form.Text>
    :''
    }
    
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group>
  <Form.Label>Select Role</Form.Label>
    <Multiselect 
        options={roles} 
        // selectedValues={selectedValue}  
        onSelect={onSelectRoles} 
        onRemove={onRemoveRole} 
        displayValue="name" 
        className={errors['roles'] ? "is-invalid" : ""}
    />
    {errors['roles'] ? 
    <Form.Text className="text-danger">
      {errors['roles']}
    </Form.Text>
    :''
    }
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group>
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control className={errors['password'] ? "is-invalid" : ""} type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Password" />
    {errors['password'] ? 
    <Form.Text className="text-danger">
      {errors['password']}
    </Form.Text>
    :''
    }
  </Form.Group>
  <Button variant="success" size="sm" type="submit">
    Create
  </Button>
</Form>
</Modal.Body>
</Modal>
    );
  }

  Create.prototype= {
    handleClose: propTypes.func.isRequired,
    show: propTypes.bool.isRequired,
    roles: propTypes.array.isRequired
  }

export default Create;
```

when i add new user by using saveUser createEntityAdapter, not getting relational data "role" & getting error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem in my code, actually createEntityAdpter addone works looks like below

```
Adapter.addOne(state, payload.data);
```

i was passing only id in addOne function, as below

```
[saveUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
  state.loading = false,
  state.status = HTTP_STATUS.FULFILLED
  if(!payload.errors){
    userAdapter.addOne(state, payload.id), //wrong approach
    state.message = payload.message
  }
```

it should be pass full object in addOne function of createEntityAdapter

```
[saveUser.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
  state.loading = false,
  state.status = HTTP_STATUS.FULFILLED
  if(!payload.errors){
    userAdapter.addOne(state, payload.user),
    state.message = payload.message
  }
```

Now, this will work fine. now i am getting all relational data too in response.